# Click() по Flash плееру с помощью Selenium

Tags: java, flash, selenium

Доброго времени суток, появилась такая задача: "Нажимать на элементы управления flash плеера средствами Selenium", пробовал нажать  по координатам(что меня вполне устраивает), но клика по плееру не происходит. Помогите пожалуйста найти решение

Вот так я пробовал это реализовать:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveByOffset(354, 220).click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за проявленное внимание, после 3-х дневного парсинга интернета решение так и не нашлось, к сожалению политика безопасности Adobe Flash не позволяет производить клик по плееру (он находиться в какой-то "песочнице" ), я решил вопрос с помощью JS запросов через консоль, есть еще решение с библиотекой Robot [читать тут](http://firstdev.org/post/programmirovanie/java/java-robot/), но она использует твою реальную мышку, а это не вариант для удаленных тестов. Так, что если есть возможность, советую использовать JS запросы, в этом я нашел, как минимум, два плюса:

1. Действия с плеером происходят и в логе это видно.
2. Проверка работоспособности JS никогда не бывает лишней.

Вот как-то так.

ps: Не судите строго, я только начал изучать все это и буду рад любой конструктивной критике с доступным объяснением.

Answer (score 0):

```
clickAt(flash_web_element,"23,66");
```

23 и 66 координаты флеш объекта, если они вам известны

Comment: Не могу понять, откуда берётся этот метод clickAt() ?

Comment: он имел в виду, что надо писать
builder.moveByOffset(354, 220).click(webElement)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Comment: К сожалению `builder.moveByOffset(354, 220).click(webElement)` не эмулирует клик по самому плееру, даже если сверху плеера создать пустой `<div>`